# Timer running when game is in pause state-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I created timer like this in my game:

```
    Timer.schedule(new Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            makeComets();
        }
    }, 2);
```

I am using these code for more than 2 time in the entire game and it is working fine.

But whenever I pause the game,this timer is not getting stopped.Timer is running while in pause state.This affects the entire game play.

I found out Timer.instance().stop() and Timer.instance().stop() methods are there.

I made these call at ApplicationListener's  pause and resume callbacks.

```
@Override
public void pause() {
    gameState = GameState.PAUSE;
timerdelay = TimeUtils.nanosToMillis(TimeUtils.nanoTime());
    Timer.instance().stop();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    gameState = GameState.RESUME;
  Timer.instance().delay(TimeUtils.nanosToMillis(TimeUtils.nanoTime()) - 
  timerDelay);
    Timer.instance().start();
}
```

But my problem is not completely solved.Still timer running when game state  PAUSE is made manually.It works with device pause and resume.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above scheduled task run once with a delay of 2 seconds.

But when you run repetitive task, you don't need to pause and resume your task because your task is scheduled on `TimerThread` that is managed by LibGDX framework itself.

**EDIT**

You need to stop `Timer` by yourself because LibGDX started for you. Then start `Timer` after some time according to your requirement.

```
@Override
public void resume() {
    Timer.instance().stop();
    stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(5), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Timer.instance().start();
        }
    })));
}
```

Comment: when timer starts,If I pause the game,all other things will get paused.but makeComet() method will be executed soon after I resuming the game after sometimes.It does not wait for the 2 second delay.That delay time is already elapsed while game is in pause state.Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: @Manasa I see you've unaccepted my answer. Is there a problem with it ?

Comment: It seems accidentally  I clicked on the tick mark and answer got unaccepted.Not intentionally.Thanks for notifying.Now I accepted again.